# can't find DeviceDetectorModule In ngx-device-detector

Tags: angular

To install this library, run:

```
$ npm install ngx-device-detector --save
```

package.json

```
"ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.6",
```

Usage: Import DeviceDetectorModule in your app.module.ts

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { DeviceDetectorModule } from 'ngx-device-detector';
  ...
  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      ...
      LoginComponent,
      SignupComponent
      ...
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule,
      DeviceDetectorModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers:[
      AuthService
    ]
    ...
  })
```

But I have an error on this line:

```
import { DeviceDetectorModule } from 'ngx-device-detector';
```

error:

```
TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/ngx-device-detector/ngs-device-detector"' has no exported member 'Device Detector Module'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is here:

> Module '"../../node_modules/ngx-device-detector/ngs-device-detector"' has no exported member 'Device Detector Module'.

It means that the library does not have the `DeviceDetectorModule`. You're probably using old documentation.

In the [library docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector) it states that now you can use the service directly, without the module:

```
import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';
```

So there is no need to use the module you're trying to use.